# Azure service bus using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to create a ServiceBusClient and its failing to initiate a connection. I have added the proxy settings but made no difference. I have tried with C#, works fine.
INFO - 'servicebus.pysdk-42e0fe1c' has an exception (ServiceBusConnectionError("Failed to initiate the connection due to exception: Failed to establish websocket connection: Cannot connect to host servisbus.fdaf.af, 443

```
async def topic_send(composed_message):
    servicebus_client: ServiceBusClient
    async with ServiceBusClient(
            fully_qualified_namespace=asb_namespace,
            credential=credential,
            logging_enable=True, transport_type=TransportType.AmqpOverWebsocket,
            Dict=proxySettings) as servicebus_client:
        sender = servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(topic_name=topic_name)
        async with sender:
            message = ServiceBusMessage(composed_message)
            await sender.send_messages(message)
            print("published message")
```

Comment: Recently discovered using connection string does work but not with fully qualified namespace and with DefaultAzureCredential